# Block request if original url matches some condition .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I've got an mod_rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?some_path/?$ /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
```

This allows login attempt in wordpress to goto some_path which apache rewrites to wp-login so wordpress can handle it without having to know about this rewrite.

I'd like the block access to wp-login all together now via mod_rewrite but if I make a rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-login.php
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Now that rule block's it perfectly, except it blocks calls to /some_path too, I assume this is because mod_rewrite keeps looping though all the rules and while at first /wp-login.php doesn't match, when some_path gets rewritten to /wp-login.php it blocks it all the same.

Is there some elegant way to handle this? Basically I'd like to block requests going to /wp-login.php only when the original request_uri is wp-login, not the rewritten request_uri.

Ps. bonus points for nginx solution although that might be a different question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `REQUEST_URI` use `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /wp-login.php
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and **it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules**. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i needed, not sure how I did not find this with google... :)